# Multiple select not working in drupal8

Tags: forms, 8

I have a form element as follows :

```
$form['fieldset']['select-user'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('Select a user'),
            '#options' => select_user_dropdown_options(),
            '#description' => t('Select a user'),
            '#size' => 10,
            '#attributes' => array(
                'style' => 'width:600px',
                'multiple' => 'true'
            )
        );
```

And in the form submit handler i am processing it as follows :

```
    /**
     * #submit callback for node_adoption_transfer_form().
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $groupId = $form_state->getValue('select-user-group');
        $groupName = $form_state->getValue('group_name');
        $userId = $form_state->getValue('select-user');
        $groupName = empty($groupName) ? '' : $groupName;
        #print_r($userId);exit;
        foreach ($userId as $key => $value) {
            $query = "select * from {usergroup_user_map} where user_id=$value AND group_id ='$groupId'";
            if (count(db_query($query)->fetchObject()) > 0) {
                continue;
            } else
                db_query("insert into {usergroup_user_map} (user_id,group_name,group_id) values ($value,'$groupName','$groupId')");
        }
     }
```

But when am printing the **`$userId`** its only printing the last value , How to resolve this ?

**UPDATE**

> my issue solved .I was using '#multiple' => 'true' instead of
>   '#multiple' => TRUE , my bad ;) . That saved my day ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had same issue , but i solved like this

```
$form['fieldset']['select-user'] = array(
   '#type' => 'select',
   '#title' => t('Select a user'),
   '#options' => select_user_dropdown_options(),
   '#description' => t('Select a user'),
   '#size' => 10,
   '#multiple' => TRUE,
   '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => 'edit-select-user',
      'style' => 'width:600px',
   )
);
```

Code:
[image]

Form:
[image]

Output in submit:

[image]

Comment: It doesnt work , even multiple property of select box is not working

Comment: @icecreamJelly: updated answer with screenshots, refer that may be this will help. And also clear cache if possible.

Comment: I checked  , If its not there in attributes array , its not acting as multi select at all

Comment: **User error: "multiple" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 102 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).**

Comment: Using drupal 8.1.8 version and I am using this in EntityForm.

Comment: ohh , am using **use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;** and extending **Formbase** only , is that the issue ?

Comment: in formbase also its is working for me. Just now i checked

Comment: I see you are using **public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)** instead of **public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)** . Is that make any difference ??

Comment: This is my form

class ExampleForm extends EntityForm {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)